# Error message after using the extension "C/C++ Compile run" in VSCode

Tags: c, vscode-extensions

So  I am quite new to C and VScode and my professor advised me to install this the Linux subsystem Ubuntu and this extension " C/C++ Compile run" so I did that and when I run my code now, even as simple as Hello World, I get the following Error in the Output section:

Error: there is no registered task type 'Compile'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?

And I even get it twice for just compiling once. But only if i use the feature that is enabled by that extension, which is to compile the code with F6, instead of pressing the compile triangle on the top left corner. If i do it by clicking on that triangle, everything is fine. And tbh the error message is weird because my code still works fine and the output in the terminal is 100% correct.

So there are Requirments to that extension, but I absolutely followed the steps and got all updates and installions for Ubuntu. So if yall cant help me thats fine, because my Code still works as intended but this error messages confuses and annoys me. Also make me doubt my abilities as programmer and user of vscode and c.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by this, using open source tools inevitably ends in practical issues. I have been using VSCode with C & ARM extensions for several years and I still bump into this type of "meta" issues, be it because a tool seized development, a breaking change in an update or even OS compatibility problems. Hell, I wouldn't be surprised if your teacher was perplexed by your problem.